Updating fields in a contact
I'm currently learning about Dynamics and trying to update a contact's Preferred Contact Method field using only the emailaddress1 and telephone1 fields. When I select one of those options and fill in the corresponding field, the contact should be updated. However, I only get the exception message when I try to update the contact, otherwise, it should pop the exception message. Can you help me understand what might be causing the problem?
I done the next code, taking the value fo the field that im updating in the Preferred Contact Mtehod, and i don´t know where i´m i doing wrong:
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace BasicPluginTwo
{
    public class ContactUpdatePlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];


                // Verify that the entity represents a contact.
                if (entity.LogicalName != "contact") return;

                // Check if Preferred Contact Method, Email or Phone fields
                int preferredContactMethodOption = entity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("preferredcontactmethodcode").Value;
                string email = entity.Contains("emailaddress1") ? entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("emailaddress1") : string.Empty;
                string phone = entity.Contains("telephone1") ? entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone1") : string.Empty;

                // Validate fields based on Preferred Contact Method
                if ((preferredContactMethodOption == 2 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) || (preferredContactMethodOption == 3 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Preferred Contact Method requires a corresponding non-empty contact detail.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


you didn't write on which attributes your plugin is running, and more important if the plugin is triggered but the fields you are extracting (preferredcontactmethodcode, emailaddress1, telephone1) are not part of the update pipeline, the plugin will not work, you will need to register an image to always get the field values

I don't quite understand this part of your explanation, would help a lot if you could clarify :)

When I select one of those options and fill in the corresponding field, the contact should be updated. However, I only get the exception message when I try to update the contact, otherwise, it should pop the exception message.

However I will assume I understood what you are trying to achieve.
If you want to notify the user that the requiered field for the prefered contact method is empty or not valid, I would move this logic to a WebResource.
I would add this check on the OnLoad event of the corresponding form and in the OnChange event of preferredcontactmethodcode
